# Migrating servers with Plesk

Tags: migration

We've recently bought a new server with plesk 9.2.3 and would like to migrate all our data from our old server (plesk 8.6.0) to the new server.

The problem is that we can't use the migration manager since we don't have root access to the old server, we merely have a reseller account that holds all our domains.
Thus using the migration manager is no option.

How would i best go ahead now? I'm thinkin in the lines of pulling backups from each individual domain on the old server and loading them into the new server but don't know if that'll work.

Anyone suggestions or idea's on how to most efficiently move over about 100 domains?

Edit: I noticed that backing up a domain on the old server and restoring it on the new server doesn't work, looks like there is some kind of version conflict between the two plesk versions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have SSH/RDP on the new server

- Backup the client if you're running Plesk on Linux OR backup all your domains if you're running Plesk on Windows (Client backup is not available there)
- Setup the new Plesk server and make sure that you have the same license limitations (for example if you had PowerPack on the old server, make sure you have it on the new one too)
- Download the client/domain backups and upload them to the new server
- Run this command on each of the backup archives:

  /usr/local/psa/bin/pre9-backup-convert -v convert -d /var/lib/psa/dumps backup-file

for Linux

```
"%plesk_bin%\pre9-backup-convert.exe" --source=C:\backup-file --destination="C:\Program Files\Parallels\Plesk\Backup"
```

for Windows

and then select the Backup option from the home page to get to the Backup/Restore page. There you'll be able to restore the files you've just converted. That's it! Afterwards, check if everything is OK (namely DNS records and IPs)